# Are there packages in Julia that estimates the marginal means or marginal effects?

Tags: julia, mixed-models, marginal-effects

I am new to Julia and i estimated some multilevel regressions using Mixed Models. Everything worked perfectly fine but i would like to estimate the marginal means or marginal effects. In R there are two packages that i am aware of for that regard: `emmeans` and `ggeffects`. Are there similar packages in Julia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Julia, there is now [Effects.jl](https://github.com/beacon-biosignals/effects.jl), which uses the same technique as the `effects` package in R (which is what `ggeffects` uses for its computation).

Since your question is tagged `mixed-models`, you might also consider [JellyMe4](https://github.com/palday/JellyMe4.jl) which adds support for `lme4`/MixedModels to RCall.

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe there is a good package for this at the moment, though you could use [RCall.jl](https://juliainterop.github.io/RCall.jl/dev/) and process your data there. Or, if you don't mind doing it manually - you could possibly calculate it from the `predict()` method from [GLM.jl](https://juliastats.org/GLM.jl/v0.11/)